# MIUI Problem. I can't control "display pop-up windows while running in the background" in the app

Tags: android, permissions, xiaomi, miui

I can't control "display pop-up windows while running in the background" in app. I can only redirect to the other permissions page. How do I check if this permission is enabled or disabled? I want to check in the app.

https://hizliresim.com/UoGpRq

This code redirects.

```
        intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
        intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", context.getPackageName());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (isIntentAvailable(intent, context)) {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Intent is not available!");
        }
```

Comment: im facing same proble. Did you have any solution?

Comment: No, I could not find. I'm investigating. If you find, please say.

Comment: @ChuongLeVan Did you find it?

Comment: i have no idea. really hard to find out.

Comment: @ChuongLeVan I'm looking for questions on stackoverflow on this topic and seeing your comments. You still haven't found it. I haven't found the solution either. Should we email Xiaomi developers? If only we could find them ...

Comment: I think there is nothing we can do about it. maybe its a Xiaomi secure system. if we have a big app like facebook, we can.